# jcarousel hide both arrows if a number of items is less than X

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

So I have this bit of code and I tried putting it in `.load` and `.ready` functions but it just doesn't work because the carousel isn't fully loaded yet.

```
var num_rec = "${recProducts.size()}";
if(num_rec < 5){
    jQuery(".jcarousel-prev").attr("disabled", true);
    jQuery(".jcarousel-next").attr("disabled", true);
    jQuery(".jcarousel-clip").attr("style", 'postion:relative; width:312px;');
}
```

Now this code runs, but is overridden by the carousel options.
Is there an option for the carousel I can use that will run a function to run this code?

If I have only four things in my carousel then there is no need to show any paging because all four things will be displayed so I want to remove paging altogether and make the container a bit larger so that the picture doesn't cut off. If there are more than 4 though I need the paging.

Answer (score 0):

HA!
I wrote an extra style to the actual stylesheet. This is not quite what I was looking for, but it works. Using the CSS visibility works because there is no inline style added to the element by the carousel plugin that uses it.

```
if(num_rec < 5){                
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".pdp-main .recommendations .jcarousel-next", "visibility:hidden;");
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule(".pdp-main .recommendations .jcarousel-prev", "visibility:hidden;");
}
```

For FireFox you will have to use insertRule instead.

I would still like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this. The jQuery Rule plugin would not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified JQuery methd:

```
var total_items = jcarousel.find('li').length;
if(total_items < 5)
{                
    $('.jcarousel-control-prev, .jcarousel-control-next, .jcarousel-pagination').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var items = $('.carousel-navigation').jcarousel('items');
  total_items=items.length;
  if(total_items < 5){                
    $('.prev-navigation, .next-navigation').hide();
  }
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.